# asp.net template for monodevelop

Tags: monodevelop, c#

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, monocomplete and monodevelop(5.10.0.872-2). But it doesn't have project template of asp.net projects. I found [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770299/monodevelop-on-xubuntu-missing-asp-net). It's not allowing me to install 5.10.0.871. Is there any plan to fix this issue from Ubuntu side?

Comment: Please clarify the question: do you search for solution, or just for answer of any plans to fix this? Because in the first case the question you linked has answer *(though with important info behind the links to SO post and a blog post)*. If the latter case, then you unlikely get any answer, because of low probability for Ubuntu Mono packager to stumble upon your question. You have to [report a bug against the package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/monodevelop/+filebug) instead.

Comment: @Hi-Angel I am looking for both. The solution given there isn't working and hoping to get a permanent fix from Ubuntu also. Let me try opening a bug meanwhile.

Comment: Is that [this answer didn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37156244/2388257)?

Comment: No. It says 5.10.0.871 doesn't exist.

Comment: I'd list [all available versions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/447/how-can-i-see-all-versions-of-a-package-that-are-available-in-the-archive) of monodevelop package, and check for one starting with 5.10. And please, leave a comment to the original answer if that didn't work for you.